# Java Programming: Something like Watir-Webdriver running in background

Tags: java, webdriver, cross-platform

I have written a program in Ruby that checks a web page every so often, and performs some actions if data is found. I have written this using Watir-Webdriver.

I also want this program to run as a "daemon". The problem I had with Watir-Webdriver was that I could not run it without a browser popping up everytime.

> 1. I actually need to write this in Java? Which is best Java package thats similar in functionality to Watir-Webdriver?
> 2. Is there any way to implement this in Java - to check a webpage and do specific actions - all in the background?
> 3. Also, I would like this to be cross-platform.

Thank you in advance to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are looking for [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). It can be written in Java and many other languages.
2. Yes.  Webdriver can run different types of browsers.  You are looking for what we call a *headless driver*.  The most popular headless drivers are [HtmlUnitDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) or [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).  I personally prefer GhostDriver, as it runs a more modern version of Javascript.
3. All Java code can be run on different platforms, so that shouldn't be a problem.